# Dialogflow and call an intent directly from fulfillment inline editor without asking the user again

Tags: dialogflow-es

I need to call an intent directly from fulfillment from the inline editor without waiting for the user to say something.

I am filling a data base, dialogflow ask for a name and the bot should only ask the missing entries from the database. So, when the user says the name, the bot should automatically ask ONLY the missing entries from the database. So far I've made it work but it need the user to retype the missing entries although the bot already knows this information.

```
    if (!doc.exists) {
      //Here I would like to call directly another intent WITHOUT asking the user to call it
    } else {
      //Here I would like to call a different intent again WITHOUT asking the user to call it
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can call an intent directly without any prompt to user with the help of `events`.
From the fulfillment, you can invoke an event with the help of `followupEventInput`.

```
if (!doc.exists) {
      response = json.dumps({
        "followupEventInput": {
            "name": name_of_event
        })
    } else {
      response = json.dumps({
        "followupEventInput": {
            "name": name_of_another_event
        })
    }
return response
```

Just make sure to give correct name of event under your intent in Dialogflow console.

[image: event]

Hope it helps.

Comment: I did this, but it says JSON.dumps is not a function.

Comment: this is python code, i think you must be coding in node, so please use node equivalent of this code.@Harry.Naeem

Comment: Oh i see, yes i'm using node

Comment: for node you can use the followup() method 
https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/classes/dialogflow.dialogflowconversation.html#followup

Answer (score 1):

Remember that an Intent matches *what the user says* and *not* what you do with that information or how you reply. So you don't "call an Intent".

If you want to prompt a user for information - go ahead and prompt them in your fulfillment.

If you want to narrow which Intent can get called when they reply, you can set a Context as part of the reply and match that as the Input Context for possible Intents. Keep in mind, however, that users can take the conversation in any direction, and not necessarily answer the question you're prompting for.

Answer (score 1):

It was with events agent.setFollowupEvent('name_of_the_event')

and in the intent yopu wish to call, you put 'name_of_the_event' as an event

Comment: it will skip the response of the current intent in which agent.setFollowupEvent('name_of_the_event') is written and directly call the follow up intent